# C# WInforms Change border style on button click event

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to change the border color of a text box (txtUser) on button click event (something like a form validation, if the input is empty then call the method that colors the border red). I did some googling and found this:

```
void myControl1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, this.txtUser.ClientRectangle, Color.Black, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
}
```

But I'm having trouble understaing where or how should I call this method, or methods with (object sender, PaintEventArgs e) as params. Any explanation is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inherit from TextBox and then override the OnPaint method. Something like this should work:

```
public class ValidateEdit : TextBox
{
    bool _InError;

    public ValidateEdit()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
    }

    public bool InError {
        get {
            return _InError;
        }
        set
        {
            _InError = value;
            Refresh();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        if (InError)
            ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, this.DisplayRectangle, Color.Red, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
    }
}
```

Comment: You _can_ do this with events without needing to create your own control.  The relevant part of the above answer is the `InError` code, which you would toggle via the validation event.  Having an inherited textbox does add the property for you directly to the control which makes managing it easier and better OO practice.